# CSS Single page nav menu with cycling content

Tags: css, html, dynamic, navigation

So this might be two questions in one.

I want to use css to allow my nav menu to determine the content of the page on hover.

So when you hover over "contacts" it will display the contact form in the content div.

I also would like the main content to cycle through a few different sets of cntent when nothing is being hovered over.

Just curious what the best way to do this is and put the least amount of load on the page load time.

Edit: The idea is to reduce the number of clicks a user will have to do in order to raise conversion rates.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to break down this problem into its component parts and solve each one separately:

1. How to cycle through content items automatically (Javascript)
2. How to show/hide divs in response to a hover event (CSS and/or Javascript)
3. Usability issues such as what happens when a user stops hovering but still wants to read the content in the displayed div.

Comment: 1 Ive seen it done in just css http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/#4 not sure If I like the solution better than js though

3 is a good point I hadn't thought through yet